# Python - Assigning variables to SNMP OIDs

Tags: python, snmp

I need to find a way to create an Python variable to OID table. I have a list of variables that need to be given SNMP OIDs that can be accessed by an SNMP client.

Thank you.

I've looked at PySNMP but I don't see any way to link a python variable to an OID.

In simple terms, I need to do something like this:

OID1 = PyVariable1
OID2 = PyVariable2
.
.
.
OIDx = PyVariablex

Comment: Can you explain a little more concretely what you are trying to do? I don't understand what you mean about "link[ing] a python variable to an OID"

Comment: PuSNMP doesn’t evolve to the stage to allow you to easily develop an SNMP agent (aka server) yet. You will have to write your own framework upon it. That’s why you won’t find much information from others.